# Poisson Distribution - Conceptual Question

Tags: probability

> $\mathbf{6.25.}$ Suppose that $10^6$ people arrive at a service station at times that are independent random variables, each of which is uniformly distributed over $(0,10^6)$. Let $N$ denote the number that arrive in the first hour. Find an approximation for $P\{N=i\}$.

I am trying to answer the question above. However, no units are provided for time; so I am not sure how I am supposed to compute the rate parameter in terms of hours. Am I missing something or has the question left out important information?

For example, if $(0,10^{6})$ represents hours, then the rate parameter for each hour is 1. If $(0,10^{6})$ instead represents days, then the rate parameter for each hour is $1/24$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the problem left out important information.  They should have given units for "$(0,10^6)$'.  Since the only time unit mentioned is hours, I'd assume they mean $10^6$ hours.